# Can questions put on hold be taken off hold

Tags: discussion

A [question I asked](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/260693/guidelines-for-developing-saas-applications-in-java) was put on hold. I have edited and instead am asking for guidance on how I can build a SAAS app. Does this question have scope to be taken off hold and attract some answers ? Or should I just re-ask the edited question ?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256567/which-edits-push-closed-questions-to-the-reopen-review-queue

Comment: FWIW [reopen reviewers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/81508) appear to be not convinced by the edit

Comment: As far as I can this, this system is very poor in providing the correct guidance on what questions are appropriate to ask here.  StackOverflow is very clear.  have code examples, don't just ask how-to without going through some level of research on your own.  Very clear.  This site seems to be about developer discussion that doesn't allow developer discussion.

Comment: @RobertBeaubien it was never about discussion.  See [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/40980) and the wording in the [tour](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour) - "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat." There is a bit of history on P.SE when it started out allowing almost anything, [and that was a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/213963). So we really try to constrain the discussions and questions that would be too broad allowing lots of poor answers.

Comment: The edit asks the same off-topic question with slightly better wording.

Comment: @MichaelT FWIW question asked by [unhappy commenter](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/260923/current-twain-wia-development-tools-techniques-c) is actually of kind clearly covered in [help/on-topic]. Being active at SO, they could probably even recognize [same kind](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic "'recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource'") that is off-topic over there, [software recommendations](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe it should be reopened because now it is far to broad of a topic to get a good answer.

Expand on each of these sub-questions you have and ask them separately and you might have better success.